# python, vtk glyphs with independent position, orientation, color, and height

Tags: python, vtk

Using Python and VTK I am trying to render 10k cylinders to visualize gradient directions. I have reviewed multiple examples on the internet but none of them shows how you can, at the same time, change the position, orientation, color and height of each rendered cylinder independently.

I know it is possible to create an actor per cylinder but with 10k cylinders that would be very slow.

The following example code is my work in progress on this problem. I first define some data for 2 cylinders and next I try to visualize them with VTK.

- What works is the position, orientation and color of the cylinders.
- What does not work is the height of each cylinder.

Possible solutions might be to use different cylinder sources to get the heights right. Yet I don't know how to apply those.

Perhaps a more experienced VTK programmer can enlighten me?

```
    from vtk import *

    # input data, every row is for a different item
    positions = [[0, 0, 0],
                 [1.5, 0, 0]]

    orientations = [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                    [0.0, 1.0, 1.0]]

    colors = [[255, 0, 0],
              [0, 255, 255]]

    heights = [1,
               2]


    # rendering of those two defined cylinders
    points = vtkPoints()
    points.InsertNextPoint(*positions[0])
    points.InsertNextPoint(*positions[1])
    polydata = vtkPolyData()
    polydata.SetPoints(points)

    color_def = vtkUnsignedCharArray()
    color_def.SetNumberOfComponents(3)
    color_def.SetNumberOfTuples(polydata.GetNumberOfPoints())
    color_def.InsertTuple3(0, *colors[0])
    color_def.InsertTuple3(1, *colors[1])
    polydata.GetPointData().SetScalars(color_def)

    pointNormalsArray = vtkDoubleArray()
    pointNormalsArray.SetNumberOfComponents(3)
    pointNormalsArray.SetNumberOfTuples(polydata.GetNumberOfPoints())
    pointNormalsArray.SetTuple(0, orientations[0])
    pointNormalsArray.SetTuple(1, orientations[1])
    polydata.GetPointData().SetNormals(pointNormalsArray)

    cyl_source = vtkCylinderSource()
    cyl_source.SetResolution(10)
    cyl_source.SetHeight(0.8)
    cyl_source.SetRadius(0.1)
    cyl_source.Update()

    glyph = vtkGlyph3D()
    glyph.SetInputData(polydata)
    glyph.SetSourceConnection(cyl_source.GetOutputPort())
    glyph.SetColorModeToColorByScalar()
    glyph.SetVectorModeToUseNormal()
    glyph.ScalingOff()

    mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper()
    mapper.SetInputConnection(glyph.GetOutputPort())
    actor = vtkActor()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)
    ren = vtkRenderer()
    ren.AddActor(actor)

    renwin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    renwin.AddRenderer(ren)
    iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    iren.SetRenderWindow(renwin)
    renwin.Render()
    iren.Initialize()
    iren.Start()
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the scaling property for modifying the height? But I think it will also modify the diameter proportionally

Comment: hej Lib, thanks for you comment. I have indeed tried to use the scaling property but I have noticed two things. The first is that it interferes with using the scaling for the colors and the second is that, like you state, the diameter increases as well. My guess is that I have to go with a vtkProgrammableGlyphFilter to get it to work. Anyone tried?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/Visualization/ClampGlyphSizes has something similar to what you need (I haven't tried):

```
# Tell glyph which attribute arrays to use for what
glyph.SetInputArrayToProcess(0,0,0,0,'Elevation')       # scalars
glyph.SetInputArrayToProcess(1,0,0,0,'RTDataGradient')      # vectors
# glyph.SetInputArrayToProcess(2,0,0,0,'nothing')       # normals
glyph.SetInputArrayToProcess(3,0,0,0,'RTData')      # colors
```

From the documentation http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkGlyph3D.html#details :

> You can set what arrays to use for the scalars, vectors, normals, and
>   color scalars by using the SetInputArrayToProcess methods in
>   vtkAlgorithm. The first array is scalars, the next vectors, the next
>   normals and finally color scalars.

Comment: I haven't managed to get this to work, but it would probably not work anyway. The glyph sizes controlled by those parameters also control the radius of the cylinders. If it would work it would scale both the height as well as the radius of the cylinders, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

vtkGlyphMapper and vtkGlyph3DMapper allow you to set a 3-dimensional ScaleArray, which you can then add to the point data:

```
glyph.SetScaleArray("CylinderScales")
scaleArray = vtkDoubleArray()
scaleArray.SetName("CylinderScales")
scaleArray.SetNumberOfComponents(3)
scaleArray.SetNumberOfTuples(polydata.GetNumberOfPoints())
scaleArray.SetTuple(0, (1, 1, 1))
scaleArray.SetTuple(1, (1, 1, 2))
polydata.GetPointData().AddArray(scaleArray)
```

The second cylinder should be twice as tall as the first, unless I got my axes wrong.